# Why differentiate predicate and non-predicate versions for generic algorithms?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, generic-programming, std

The standard library does differentiate predicate and non-predicate versions of generic algorithms. For example, `std::sort()` looks like:

```
template< class RandomIt >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last );

template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );
```

Is there any problem in just writing the following?

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare = std::less<void>>
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp = Compare{});
```

Comment: There was no such thing as default template arguments for function templates in C++03.

Comment: @T.C. So, suppose we just redesign the whole thing, should the second form be preferred?

Comment: @T.C. I believe the default template argument thing is actually an answer.

Comment: @BoBTFish I think `std::less` does just that (`operator <`). No?

Comment: @Lingxi You can specialize `std::less` for your types and make it do something other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pretty much historical reasons.

C++98/03 didn't have default template arguments for function templates, so it had to use two overloads. And changing it afterwards can break user code.

> So, suppose we just redesign the whole thing, should the second form
>   be preferred?

That's what the [current Ranges TS working draft](http://wg21.link/N4560) does.